# Why is Firestore WhereArrayContains not fetching expected data in project but fetches it in console?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection document in Firebase Firestore that contains multiple data including a list of strings. In code, I am trying to fetch any document whose list contains a specific string for example, I made 1 document for testing and it doesn't fetch it in code as expected, when I tried the same query in the console (the Firebase website) it worked just fine.

My Firestore:
[image]

My code:

```
int limit = 6;
int startingIndex = 0;

void GetPatientsInHospital()
{
    CollectionReference collectionRef = FirebaseAPI.firestore.Collection("patients");
    Query query = collectionRef.WhereArrayContains("hospitals", UserData.doctor_hospital_id).OrderByDescending("EditedAt").Limit(limit).StartAt(startingIndex);

    query.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWith((querySnapshotTask) =>
    {
        if (querySnapshotTask != null && querySnapshotTask.Exception != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(querySnapshotTask.Exception.Message))
            Debug.LogError(querySnapshotTask.Exception.Message);
        if (querySnapshotTask != null && querySnapshotTask.Result != null && querySnapshotTask.Result.Documents != null)
        {
            foreach (DocumentSnapshot doc in querySnapshotTask.Result.Documents)
            {
                Patient patient = new Patient();
                patient.fullname = doc.GetValue<string>("Name");
                patient.Patient_Data.first_name = doc.GetValue<string>("FirstName");
                patient.Patient_Data.middle_name = doc.GetValue<string>("MiddleName");
                patient.Patient_Data.last_name = doc.GetValue<string>("LastName");
                patient.Patient_Data.phoneNumber = doc.GetValue<string>("Phone");
                patient.Patient_Data.email = doc.GetValue<string>("Email");
                patient.Patient_Data.serial_number = doc.GetValue<string>("SerialNumber");
                patient.Patient_Data.nationalID = doc.GetValue<string>("NationalID");
                hospitalPatients.Add(doc.Id, patient);
            }

            Reload_PatientScroller_Data();
            loadingSpinner.SetActive(false);
        }
    });
}
```

My rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow create;
      allow update;
    }
  }
}
```

I have other code where I create and update this document programmatically and it works fine, it's just this piece of code that fails to fetch what I need. I have debugged and the doctor_hospital_id variable had exactly that 1 one value in the hospital array in the screenshot I provided, but the documents still come back with size 0.

Comment: `StartAt` does not take a number index.  You're only supposed to use it when implementing pagination of results. I suggest reviewing the documentation on that to figure out if you're using it correctly.

Comment: Also you should not snow images of code on Stack Overflow, including your security rules.  You can easily copy and paste them into your question as code.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks I edited the rules, regarding the StartAt and limit, I am using pagination and I do have a swie up to load more functionality that calls this function again with the updated index

Comment: @DougStevenson I also have a similar code snippit in the project where im looking for a specific patient using his phone number (using WhereEqualTo) and it works just fine, but if I add WhereArrayContains right before the WhereEqualTo it never fetches anything

Comment: Please show us the query that you're performing in the Console.

Comment: @AlexMamo its the exact same as this one without the limit and starting index